# Get count of added violations using Sonar REST api

Tags: web-services, rest, sonarqube

I have a need to get the count of added violations from the previous analysis. I can get the same from the dashboard, but I need the rest api provided by Sonar to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research and found that this

```
http://host/api/resources?resource=419370&metrics=new_violations&includetrends=true
```

serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below api for the same.

```
http://host:port/api/issues/search?createdAfter=2015-09-17T13:00:00+0100&statuses=OPEN&componentKeys=passyourprojectKey
```

You can pass the timestamp too of your last analysis 
You can find the last analysis timestamp using below api

```
http://host:portapi/resources?resource=projectKey&includetrends=true
```

Comment: Thanks Jitendra.. That definitely works.. But this http://host/api/resources?resource=419370&metrics=new_violations&includetrends=true gives me the count in a single request.